# How will a poor grade affect future job opportunities?

Tags: job-search, internship, student

I got a C- in a programming course during my first year at university (I'm currently in my second) and I'm worried that because of this grade, I'll be rejected from employers like Deloitte or Booz Allen Hamilton.

I had a programming job during that year as well, but the grade looks really bad on my transcript.

Could that grade keep me back from possible jobs with big companies? Could it do so even if I have job experience?

Comment: What are your grades like since then? Generally, individual grades matter far less than your overall GPA, and your GPA only matters for your first job after school. After your first job, it's all about what experience you have. The grades won't matter.

Comment: All my other grades are fine (As and Bs). I know companies will be comparing my transcript with other candidates because I'm in a very competitive field. I'm trying to make my job experience in college look good, so that the grade won't matter as much.

Comment: Just looked it up. 70% is a poor grade? Huh? That's considered *cum laude* in some systems.

Comment: Yes you're finished now.

Comment: lol. Well if overall GPA seems to be more of the attraction I won't have to worry as much about it.

Comment: @Lilienthal it is? Why employ someone who is wrong 30% of the time?

Comment: @Kilisi Because people aren't perfect?  Because you'd be a fool to compare educational grading systems with real world performance? Hell, I could go off on an endless tirade about this but this isn't the place to discuss grading systems. I commented because this grade is not at all poor by European standards and I have a hunch that this is another typically American thing, which the comparison to GPA seems to confirm.

Comment: @Lilienthal yeah I just jokingly mentioned it, because I once got 98% on a qualification and my shocked boss asked me if that means I'm wrong 2% of the time... I'm pretty much in agreement with Keshlams answer

Comment: Does your degree program include other programming related courses? Typically you'll have an introductory course, and then additional courses covering deeper or more specialized areas.

Comment: I got an A in my intro to programming course then a c- in my advanced programming course. I had a difficult programming job at the same time for my professor, which didn't help my grade.

Comment: @Kilisi Ah, my mistake, I should have realised you were being sarcastic. I guess I've seen this line of thinking way too often in otherwise reasonable adults.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depends on what the rest of your grades look like from here on out.

Having a miserable frade in Freshman year is not uncommon; many people need a term of two to adjust to being responsible for themselves, and many schools have tried making the Freshman year pass/fail for exactly that reason.

So one bad grade just marks you as a typical semi-clueless froshling, and isn't by itself a big deal. Focus on doing better in the rest of your classes.

***However,*** if that class is a foundation for the rest of your major, I ***strongly*** recommend that you make yourself go back and learn the material properly. That C- is telling you that you don't have mental tools you may need, and that may impact the rest of your grades.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it's the implication of the grade and not the grade itself.  It doesn't affect the hiring so much as it may make the job more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The companies you listed are government contractors or financial systems. As such they do extensive background vetting prior to employment. The first thing they look at is if you had a history of dishonesty. If you choose to cheat, lie, and push your way to make a better grade, then they will reject you.

As far as grades though, no most companies don't care so long as you got a degree. Transcripts are usually for internship but full time jobs generally don't look at grades or transcripts only that you got a degree.